# How do I make a function in Scheme?

Tags: list, function, scheme, racket

I need to create a function in Scheme using drRacket that gets a list of numbers as an argument and returns the largest number.
I've never coded using Scheme before so I really need help!
The testcase is something like this:
(maximEl '(3 5 7 9 1 3))
9

Answer (score 1):

I think it's the easiest way to get the largest number,

```
(define (max-el ls)
  (if (null? (cdr ls)) 
      (car ls)
      (let ((m (max-el (cdr ls))))
        (if (> (car ls) m) (car ls) m))))
```